# How to prove that the commuting matrices form a vector space of an image of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have matrix A and its commuting matrices, how to prove that they form a vector space C(A)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
(aC+B)A-A(aC+B)=aCA+BA-aAC-AB=a(CA-AC)+(BA-AB)
$$